# Access updated global variable python

Tags: python, python-3.x, global-variables, global

I have two files:

**script1.py :**

```
myValue = 0

def addition(a_value):
    a_value += 1
    return a_value

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myValue = addition(myValue)
    myValue = addition(myValue)
    print(myValue)
```

**script2.py :**

```
from script1 import *

def getMyValue():
    my_new_value = addition(myValue)
    print(my_new_value)

getMyValue()
```

When `script1` is executed it returns `2`, and this is what I want.
But when `script2` is executed, it returns `1`. How can I get the preserved result `2` from `script2`?

If I want to execute `addition()` multiple times and always get the updated result in `script2` instead of getting `1` every time?
Thank you for your replies.

Comment: "How can I get the preserved result 2 from script2" - there has never been a `2` anywhere in all of this, so I fail to see what your question means. Could you clarify?

Comment: What I am trying to say is that when script1 is executed, i get the output 2, because the addition() function is executed 2 times. I need to get the same output with script2, but it returns only one. Like i want to get the updated variable myValue at 2. Sorry for my english.

Comment: OK, but when you `import` it instead of running it as a standalone script, the part in `if __name__ == '__main__':` doesn't run, so there is no `2` anywhere. Maybe your question is actually https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do

Comment: Don't import globals with `import *` - it doesn't do what you think it does. (Globals and `import *` are rarely a good idea even on their own, but put them together and you get even more problems.)

Comment: Also what Thierry said.

Comment: What is the end goal for your code? There's likely a better way to do it than having a variable in `script1` that you need in `script2`, i.e. making the code in `script1` a class, but it depends on what you ultimately want done with your code

Comment: @RolvApneseth I am actually completely rewriting my code so it will be a more OOP approach.

Comment: That's probably for the best, hope it works out for you